# Implement the function using only four NAND gates

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

$Z = XY’ + X’Y$, using only for **NAND** gates

I can only reduce this to five **NAND** gates, and can't figure out how to get four.

**My work:**

I took the De Morgan's Law $Z = [XY' + X'Y]'$

$= (X' + Y)(X + Y')$

$= X'X + X'Y' + XY + YY'$ ( Distributive Law )

$= X'Y' + XY$ ( Complement Law )

When I create the hardware logic diagram for this new function I receive five **NAND** gates.

Comment: Your `Z` is `X XOR Y`. See [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/84803) to [How to minimize the gates in implementation?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84714/how-to-minimize-the-gates-in-implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Check the truth table of this one:

[image]

After discovering that we have the XOR function, you can find explanations [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43342/how-to-construct-xor-gate-using-only-4-nand-gate) xor [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$(X (XY)')' = (X Y')'.$$